# Excel - Create Define Name with merging two or more list for validation list

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I working for a work project and we are using an excel file to import our configuration to system.
I am currently stuck to make a Define Name with the merge of 2 list like this
[image]

After defined the list I want to use it in Validation Data like this
[image]

I found a way to merge the 2 list but I am not able to use in Data Validation because excel doesn't see the result like an 'array' but as a single value
[image]

If I try to use a Define Name that contains the result of the merge, Excel gives this error

> The list source must be a delimited list or a reference to single row or column

[image]

Comment: Why are you merging the two lists into a single comma-separated string? Why not merge them into a single vertical worksheet range?

Comment: Because I dont want to create a sheet to contains that datas

Comment: But, unless you hard-code the values into the List Source box, a Data Validation List must refer to an actual worksheet range, so you don't have a choice.

Comment: @Teo230 As you make a list of comma separated values, you can also make a temporary range of cells values. Put this formula to `Z1` cell `=TOCOL(A2:B10,1)`. Then is defined name list use this formula in List selection `=Z1#`.

Comment: @Harun24hr so in any case I have to define a column to contains that datas(?) :/

Comment: @Teo230 Yes, you have to do that for using to name manager.

Comment: @Harun24hr Ok, I found a simple way using VSTACK formula

Comment: @Teo230 Can you share it so that we can learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use commas value in name manager for Data Validation, so I create a custom column to merge the two list and use is as source for my Data Validation

[image]

1. I create two Define Name called "List1" and "List2" that contain their specific data
2. I use the formula `VSTACK` to create a merged column data (ex. `=VSTACK(List1, List2)`)
3. I create a Define Name called "MergedList" that contains the merged datas
4. I used "MergedList" as Data Validation list type

Comment: I was thinking to use `TOCOL()` --> `=TOCOL((List1,List2),3)` you get an option to ignore error and blanks values as well. Where `List1` `C2:C100` and `List2` is `D2:D100` or make those list as structured table reference.

Comment: `=TOCOL()` support only one array

Comment: But you are stacking one upon the other? did you try using `TOCOL()` the way i have mentioned?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes I tried, I dont care about the order, so both are good, but `VSTACK` formula support multiple arrays

Comment: Ok. Good to know and thank you for the share. Ensure to accept your own answer, so that it helps someone in the future